# Как создать идеальную взаимосвязь между фрагментом и активностью?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

У меня очень много `view` как во фрагменте, так и в активности. Но при создании фрагмента мне нужно получить некие данные от активности. Я переопределил конструктор фрагмента, но так делать нельзя. **Почему?**

Методы есть как во фрагменте, так и в активности. Как мне их правильно вызывать? У меня такая каша сейчас получается, вообще не читабельный, уже путаюсь сам.

Comment: Не идеальную, а всмысле, принятую и всем понятную

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Активити и фрагменты управляются системой. Поэтому не надо вмешиваться в работу их конструторов. Для получения данных в фрагменте из активити можно сделать так:

1. Создать интерфейс с нужными методами.
2. Реализовать его в активити.
3. Создать в фрагменте поле с типом интерфейса.
4. В фрагменте в `onAttach()` проверять является ли `getActivity()` экемпляром интерфейса из п.1 и присваивать оную полю фрагмента из п.3. В `onDetach()` присваивать полю из п.3 `null`
5. Теперь во фрагменте при нужде обращения к активити используйте интерфейс (поле из п.3) проверяя его на `null

---

Если же вам нужны во фрагменте данные из актвити только при создании оного то передавайте из через `Bundle` и метод `Fragment#setArguments(Bundle args)`

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял

Answer (score 4):

Переопределять конструктор нежелательно потому, что жизненный цикл фрагмента управляется мендежером фрагментов. Если операционная система уничтожит активность фрагмента, например, при смене ориентации экрана, нестандартный конструктор не будет вызван в процессе восстановления.

В книге "[Android. Программирование для профессионалов](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/135513511/)" рекомендуется использовать фабричный метод и `Bundle`:

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SOME_ID = "some_id";

    public static SomeFragment newInstance(UUID someId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_SOME_ID, someId);
        SomeFragment fragment = new SomeFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        UUID someId = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_SOME_ID);
        ...
    }
}

public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    public void someMethod() {
        Fragment someFragment = SomeFragment.newInstance(someId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Использовать  в фрагменте конструктор, отличный от конструктора по умолчанию нельзя, потому что при любом взаимодействии активити и фрагмента, она всегда использует конструктор по умолчанию (без параметров) и соответственно ваш фрагмент "упадет", так как не получит данных через конструктор.

Активити и фрагмент отдельные компоненты, правильным подходом ООП будет их низкая связанность, что значит, что они не могут напрямую вызывать методы друг друга. Это решает, в частности, такую проблему, что любая активити сможет отобразить любой фрагмент и наоборот, любой фрагмент будет работать в произвольной активити.
С другой стороны, поскольку фрагмент является зависимым от активити и без нее существовать не может, допустимым считается вызов методов фрагмента напрямую из активити, хоть это и накладывает определенные ограничения на его использование (больше переиспользование).

Рекомендуемые практики по коммуникациям между активити и фрагментом [изложены в официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) и много раз обсуждались, в том числе и на этом ресурсе.
В направлении от фрагмента к активити - интерфейс обратного вызова (колбэк). В направлении от активити к фрагменту - `Bundle` с аргументами при старте, такой же колбэк в обратную строну, если требуется обособить фрагмент (может использоваться в разных активити и проектах) или прямой вызов методов фрагмента в процессе работы.

Вместо конструктора используется передача аргументов из активити в фрагмент через `Bundle`:

```
 DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putInt("index", index);
 f.setArguments(args);
```

или реализация в самом фрагменте метода получения экземпляра с аргументами:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public static MyFragment newInstance(int index) {
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }
}
```

тогда создание фрагмента (и передача аргументов) производится так:

```
Fragment myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance(index);
```

это позволяет инкапсулировать логику фрагмента в самом фрагменте и сократить код при многократных вызовах фрагмента.

Получение данных производится в самом фрагменте методом `getArguments()`, который вернет `Bundle`:

```
int index = getArguments.getInt("index");
```

или (когда значений в Bundle несколько):

```
Bundle b =  getArguments();
int index = b.getInt("index");
```

Все изложенное выше, стандартные подходы, рекомендуемые для коммуникаций средствами системы. Лично мое мнение, что гораздо более удачным решением коммуникаций в приложении вообще (а не только между активити и его фрагментом) будет использование шины, вроде библиотеки EventBus